# AVFoundation classes not resolved in OSX xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, text-to-speech

I started a new Xcode project as a command line / OSX / Swift application.  I import AVFoundation and add the following code to top level scope after also importing foundation.

```
  let string = "Hello, World!"
  let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: string)
  utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

  let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
  synthesizer.speakUtterance(utterance)
```

The compiler complains about unresolved identifier for `AVSpeechUtterance`.  I have also attempted this in a Cocoa Application as opposed to Command Line one.  I have also tried linking against AVFoundation, although I thought this was recently made unnecessary.

Why does my xcode project not compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe those only exist for iOS.  On OS X, the similar feature is available via `NSSpeechSynthesizer`.